# Объединить частично повторяющиеся строки MS SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, база-данных

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как преобразовать тип данных varchar в bigint в данном случае? Или как по другому не учитывать столбец А при группировке и не используя агрегатные функции (т.к. если одинаковых значений в столбце id будет 3, то AVG() выдаст неверный результат)?

id(int), A(varchar(200)), B(varchar(200))

```
SELECT * INTO #A_B FROM AB
SELECT * INTO A_B_res FROM (SELECT #A_B.id, CAST(AVG(A) AS bigint) A, STRING_AGG(#A_B.A, ', ') A FROM #A_B
GROUP BY #A_B.id) #A_B
```

Выдаёт: Тип данных операнда varchar недопустим для оператора avg.

Исходная таблица (АВ):

```css
table{border: 1px solid grey;}
th{border: 1px solid grey;}
td{border: 1px solid grey;}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><th>id</th><th>A</th><th>B</th></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>7</td><td>7</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>15</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td>5</td><td>31</td><td>31</td></tr>
<tr><td>7</td><td>127</td><td>127</td></tr>
<tr><td>8</td><td>255</td><td>17</td></tr>
<tr><td>9</td><td>511</td><td>73</td></tr>
<tr><td>10</td><td>1023</td><td>11</td></tr>
<tr><td>11</td><td>2047</td><td>23</td></tr>
<tr><td>11</td><td>2047</td><td>89</td></tr>
</table>
```

Нужно получить:

```css
table{border: 1px solid grey;}
th{border: 1px solid grey;}
td{border: 1px solid grey;}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><th>id</th><th>A</th><th>B</th></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>7</td><td>7</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>15</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td>5</td><td>31</td><td>31</td></tr>
<tr><td>6</td><td>63</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>7</td><td>127</td><td>127</td></tr>
<tr><td>8</td><td>255</td><td>17</td></tr>
<tr><td>9</td><td>511</td><td>73</td></tr>
<tr><td>10</td><td>1023</td><td>11</td></tr>
<tr><td>11</td><td>2047</td><td>23, 89</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в вопрос и метки СУБД и что конкретно не работает в вашем запросе.

Comment: Ничего понять невозможно. Отформатируйте текст вопроса до вменяемого вида.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если в столбце только цифры, то замените

```
CAST(AVG(A) AS bigint)
```

на

```
AVG(CAST(A AS bigint))
```